# Adicionar valor à tabela SQL ao invés de substituir

Tags: sql, sql-update

Utilizando o seguinte código:

```
UPDATE `login` SET diasvip = '".+$_POST["qntvip"]."' WHERE userid = '".$_POST["userid"]."'
```

Quando eu executo, ele substitui os `diasvip` pelo valor postado ao invés de somar o valor postado aos já existentes na tabela. Como eu faço a operação de soma?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se você quer somar ao que já existe você deve fazer esta conta, assim:

```
"UPDATE `login` SET diasvip = diasvip + " . $_POST["qntvip"] . " WHERE userid = '".$_POST["userid"] . "'"
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Update/AddValue.sql).

Note que você está montando uma *string* então o sinal de mais já deveria estar dentro do texto, o que você coloca fora do texto é apenas o que varia.

E você não deve colocar apóstrofe em todos os dados, apenas quando for caracteres, no caso da quantidade que é um número, não deve ter.

Note que está forma é extremante insegura, eu reveria isto para não sofrer SQL Injection.

Comment: Perfeito isso mesmo ;) Obrigado.

Comment: Esqueci desculpe rsrs. Resposta marcada